# Как получить кукисы из запроса*?

Tags: c#, cookie

Есть код, который делает запрос к серверу. Изначально он имел вид такой. Но мне пришлось его изменить, так как хотелось корректно закрыть `stream`.

```
 using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
```

Я его привел к этому виду, однако не совсем понятно как получить кукисы из запроса.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 20000;
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Do something with result
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Может получить кукисы ответа?

Вместо `WebResponse response =` пропишите `HttpWebResponse response =`

А у этого класса есть свойство [Cookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies(v=vs.110).aspx)

А для установки в отношении HttpWebRequest - почти также, но через контейнер, см. [how to use cookies with HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972643/how-to-use-cookies-with-httpwebrequest)